# How To Find Volume Using Integrals Under Many Curves and Shapes(Specifically a skull)

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, cross-sections

For a calculus project, I need to find the theorized volume of a shape made from curves and objects but the problem is I have so many shapes and different types of graphs that I have no clue how to find the volume of my skull.
This is my graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i1xwzjdhau)

I apologize if it is hard to comprehend but I would greatly appreciate any help.
Do I just add all the integrals together with the points of intersection, or is it way more complicated? Also, is this even possible to do? I have to use cross-sections and  I am not even sure there is a way to split up the graph in ways in which I can accomplish this.
Thank you very much for your input.